# Proof of $ax\le bx, x>0 \Rightarrow a \le b$ using only field axioms

Tags: analysis

I'm reading *ELEMENTARY CLASSICAL ANALYSIS (2nd, Marsden), 1.1.2 Proposition*.

How can I prove $ax\le bx \land x>0 \implies a \le b$ using only sixteen field axioms?
My proof was

- Prove $\forall x\in F, \quad  x^2\ge0$.
- $x \ge 0, (x^{-1})^2\ge0\implies x^{-1}\ge0$
- $(-a+b)x\ge0, x^{-1}\ge0\implies a\le b$

but it seems to be too complex.
Is there an easier way to prove it?

Comment: How is the order $\leq$ defined on an arbitrary field $F$ ?

Comment: @learner
relation $\le$ is defined by 6 axioms :
Partial Ordering : reflexivity, anti-symmetry, transitivity,

Linear Ordering : $\forall x, y,$ either $x \le y$ or $y \le x$,

compatibility 1 : $x \le y$ then $x+z \le y+z$,

compatibility 2 : $0\le x, 0\le y,$ then $0 \le xy$

Comment: I don't see how your second line follows.  I'd prove it: 1)prove a^2 > 0 if a ne 0.  Therefore 1= 1^2 > 0.  Then if x > 0 and 1/x le 0 then 1.1/x =1 not > 0.  So 1/x > 0.  So ax/x le bx/x.

Comment: You need the **ordered** field axioms for $(F,0,1,+,\cdot,\ge)$. - By the way, as for an exact count how many those are, consider this: **Ax1** $(F,0,+)$ is an abelian group; **Ax2**  $(F\setminus \{0\},1,\cdot)$ is an abelian group; **Ax 3** $a\cdot (b+c)=a\cdot b+a\cdot c$; **Ax 4.** $\le$ is a linear order of $F$;  Let $P=\{\,x\in F\mid x\ge 0\,\}$, then **Ax 5.** $P+P\subseteq P$; **Ax 6.** $P\cdot P\subseteq P$; **Ax 7.** $P\cup(-P)=F$

Comment: @fleablood If so, I have to prove $1>0$, which is another proposition in my text book..in this book the axiom about 1 and 0 is $1 \ne 0$.

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen Oh, the axioms are 'Ordered Field Axioms', not 'field'. It's a mistake, sorry. Thanks!

Comment: 1 > 0 because x^2 > 0 if x doesn't equal 0.  So 1^2 > 0.

Comment: @fleablood  OH..I missed it. Thanks!!!

Comment: $1 \ne 0$ is often given as a field axiom.  Sometimes however, if trivial (single element) fields are allowed then $1 = 0$ if and only if the field has only one element.  (As for any $a \in F$, if $1 = 0$ then $a = 1*a = 0*a = 0$.  Meanwhile a field with exactly one element where e+e = e.e = e is ... boring... but it fits all field axioms).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First a remark on your proof idea:

It appears you have already shown (considering the cases $x\ge 0$ and $0\ge x$ separately) $\forall x\in F, x^2\ge 0$.

But what you want in the second line is rather something like this:
$$ x>0\to x^{-1}\ge 0\qquad(\text{or in fact $x^{-1}>0$ if you prefer)}$$
and this can be proved the way you seem to have use: As $x>0$, $x\ne 0$ and so $x^{-1}$ exists. Per first line, $(x^{-1})^2\ge 0$, hence $x^{-1}=x\cdot (x^{-1})^2$ is a product of non-negatives, hence is non-negatives.

Now you finish the main result by transforming $ax\le bx$ to $(-a+b)x\ge 0$, use that $x^{-1}\ge 0$ per second line an multiply to get $-a+b\ge 0$, which can be transformed to $a\le b$.

You ask whether there is a less complex proof, but my opinion on this is: The result from the first line is an important result of its own, hence its proof should not be counted against the proof of the main result. The same holds for the result of the second line. And after masking out these, there remains only the short proof of the third line, ad that is not very complex.

---

Nevertheless, for a complete *ab ovo* proof, you might consider proving the logically equivalent statement
$$ a>b,x>0\implies ax>bx.$$
Here, $ax\ge bx$ (i.e., $ax-bx\ge 0$) follows directly by multiplying $a-b\ge 0$ with $x\ge 0$. To complete the proof you once again need an additional (simple) result that is useful of its own  (so I'd supposedly prove it in advance and don't count its proof length against the current one): Fields do not have zero divisors (and the proof of *that* probably must use that multiplication by $0$ produces $0$).

I didn't check whether actually spelling out this proof would make it shorter than fully spelling out your proof. But one thing you might check (maybe woth both proof ideas) is: Which of the given axioms are used in the proof? You count sixteen axioms for ordered fields, and if for example fourteen of these are used, an *ab ovo* proof certainly must have more than fourteen lines (typically significantly more because we need some logic-only steps such as specialization per axiom). You could "attack" this length by checking if all axioms are really *needed*, i.e., ask the question: If I drop this or that axiom, then the axioms describe a more general structure than ordered fields - does the claim still hold for these structures? If so, a proof without the dropped axiom should be possible, and this *may* be shorter than what I have ...

An closing remark about proofs using only axioms is that even simple steps such as turning $ax\ge bx$ into $-ax+bx\ge 0$ are in fact multi-steps. Hence I won't like to be too harsh on the concept of useful intermediate results :)

Comment: Thanks! I was just looking for a simple proof, because the text I'm reading proposes 'that' proposition prior to other useful propositions($x^2\ge 0$ etc..). Maybe there is no need to find another proof!! :)

Answer (score 1):

It's tedious but prove the following:

By existence of inverses prove

If x+y = x + z then y=z

If x+y=x then y =0

If x+y = 0 y=-x

-(-x)=x

If x $\ne $ 0:

xy=xz then y=z

xy=xz then y=1

xy =1 then y =1/xz

Those are all basically done by applying inverses and are really easy.

Using distributive property and inverses prove:

0x =0 (as 0x +0x = (0+0) x=0x so 0x = 0)

If x $\ne $0 and y $\ne$ 0 then xy $\ne $0 (1=1/x*1/y*xy and 1/x*1/y*0 =0 so xy=0 would mean 1=0 which is impossible if there is more than 1 element)[a=1a = 0a =0]

(-x)y=-(xy)=x (-y) (just add inverses and distribute)

(-x)(-y) =xy.

Finally we can prove:

x > 0 implies -x < 0 (0=-x+x>-x+0=-x) and vice versa.

x>0 and y < z means xy < xz.

Pf: y  0 and by axiom x (z-y) >0, so x (z-y) +xy > xy.  So xz-xy + xy =xz > xy.

Similarly x <0 and y < z means xy > xz.

So if x>0 then $x^2 >0$ and if x <0x then $x^2 > 0$ so if x $\ne $ 0 then $x^2>0$.

So $1= 1^2 >0$

So it's easy to show if x>0 then 1/x >0 (else we get a contradiction).

So *finally*:

If $ax \le bx $ and $x > 0$ then $1/x > 0$ and $a=ax/x \le bx/x =b$.

========

Sorry if that was too much detail, but the hardest part is keeping track of what is axiom and what is very basic proposition.  The axiom is only x>0 y>0 then xy>0 and inverse existence and distribution.  All else is proposition.